# Status Code 200 or 304? which one is correct? Amazon CloudFront with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Status Code 200 is normal? or 304 is normal? 
Images are public and fixed so 365 days same images will be provided for every users.

I set Cache-Control as max-age=31536000 on Amazon S3 when I upload images.

Please help. :) Can you check how to set up correctly?

I want to save money for bandwidth.

```
General
Request URL:http://cdn.xxx.com/abcdefg.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:54.111.111.11:80


Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:459753
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:83256
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Tue, 14 Feb 2017 00:11:18 GMT
ETag:"5a6cf63186d10eb1fbe161d7de181cc6"
Last-Modified:Thu, 09 Feb 2017 12:45:31 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 b3825aee9279d95a2a68132ed5dca00f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:J9ncFq1xBjXA4MhF7hxpMIldiR-8aIzjmhAq9tTaT8EaRo54vkbjYQ==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront


Request Headers
GET /abcdefg.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: cdn.xxx.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://cdn.xxx.com/aaaaa
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.3.698203739.1486458204
```

Answer (score 0):

Status codes 200 in 304 are both OK. All errors are in the 400 range.

200 means`OK`.
304 means `Not Modified`: the cached content can be reused by the client. If you get a `304` caching works.

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes for more details.